Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): [Errno 2] No such file or directory for urtlebot3_.urdf
Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/humble/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/urdf/turtlebot3_.urdf
so how can i solve this

I guess there is a typo on your question turtlebot3_.urdf instead of urtlebot3_.urdf

From the error message, it seems the issue is that the environment variable TURTLEBOT3_MODEL is not set. This variable determines which TurtleBot3 model's URDF file is loaded.
To fix this, set the environment variable as follows:
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger # notice no spaces before or after =

You can also use other models like waffle and waffle_pi.
After setting the variable, run the launch file again. Let me know if it works.

Did you check if the .urdf file exists in that folder?
Providing more information would make it easier to find a solution
